# Using flexbox, vertically center items and respect top 150px space of flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to craft a flexbox in CSS with the following characteristics:

- Three items stacked and centered within the middle of the flexbox
- One item locked to bottom of the flexbox
- Flexbox is set to a size of 100vh and 100vw, taking up visible screen area
- **Items within flexbox must not occupy the top 150px of the flexbox.** This may push some items below the viewable area (see "Desired Result 3" in image below)
- Ideally, a pure CSS solution is feasible with the HTML elements provided

[image]

### The Problem

The vertically centered boxes won't honor the 150px space I would like to put at the top of the flexbox, and I haven't been able to create an elegant way to make sure the items don't float up past the top of the screen if I make the window too short. That is, the example in "Desired Result 3" in the image above remains elusive.

### Example Code

HTML:

```css
body {margin:0; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight:bold;}
.parentFlexBox { 
  background-color:grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top:0; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  
}
.itemA, .itemB, .itemC, .itemD { padding:5px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:5px; color:#fff;}
.itemA { background-color:red; width:50px;  margin-top:auto;}
.itemB { background-color:hotpink; width:150px; height:50px}
.itemC { background-color:purple; width:40px; height: 35px}
.itemD { background-color:blue; margin-top:auto; width: 80px;}
```

```html
<div class="parentFlexBox">
  <div class="itemA">A</div>
  <div class="itemB">B</div>
  <div class="itemC">C</div>
  <div class="itemD">D</div>
</div>
```

**Please run above code in full screen to see the issue**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

**HTML** (add two invisible flex items)

```
<div class="parentFlexBox">
    <div class="itemA">A</div>
    <div class="itemB">B</div>
    <div class="itemC">C</div>
    <div class="itemD">D</div>
    <div class="itemE">E</div><!-- invisible spacer item with 150px height -->
    <div class="itemF">F</div><!-- invisible spacer item with 120px height -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parentFlexBox { justify-content: space-between; } /* changed from `center` */

.itemA { order: 1; } /* removed `margin-top: auto` */

.itemB { order: 2; } 

.itemC { order: 3; }

.itemD { order: 5; height: 30px; } /* added `height` for centering calculation;
                                      removed `margin-top:auto` */
.itemE { 
      order: -1;  
      flex: 0 0 150px; /* don't grow, don't shrink, remain at 150px height */
      visibility: hidden;
      margin-bottom: auto; /* stick to top of container */
}

.itemF {
      order: 4;
      flex: 0 1 120px; /* don't grow, shrink proportionally, start at 120px height */
      visibility: hidden;
      margin-top: auto; /* go south as much as possible (sticks to Item D) */
}

/* NOTE: Item D has height 30px. Item F has height 120px. Together they equal height of
   Item E. Equally balanced on both ends, Items A, B & C are centered in the container. */
```

[**DEMO 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/c61x86b6/3/)

I placed the spacer divs last in the mark-up to keep with the alphabetical ordering. If you prefer to list all divs (including spacers) in order, that would eliminate the need for the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property.

Also, in the demo, the code includes borders, in case you want to see the spacers at work. Just disable the [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property.

---

**Update** (based on comment)

> Nice, a couple of questions though: 1) Possible to make it so that BCD don't change height when resizing the window? 2) Possible to make the gray background extend to contain D when window is short? 3) Possible to do items E and F as pseudocode elements?

*Question #1:* Yes. Add `flex: 0 0 <<absolute height>>` to BCD. For instance, add `flex: 0 0 50px` to each item, which tells them to stay fixed at 50px height. (Also, remove the `height` property from each rule, to avoid any potential conflict with `flex`.)

*Question #2:* Yes. Instead of limiting the container to `height: 100vh`, use `min-height: 100vh`.

*Question #3:* Yes. Remove the E and F code from the HTML and CSS, and add this to the CSS:

```
.parentFlexBox::before {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.parentFlexBox::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: auto;
  order: 4;
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/c61x86b6/6/)

Comment: Nice, a couple of questions though:
1) Possible to make it so that BCD don't change height when resizing the window?
2) Possible to make the gray background extend to contain D when window is short?
3) Possible to do items E and F as pseudocode elements?

Comment: Faaaaantastic, thank you Michael! Elegantly solved and easy to read.